# Given $x_m=4x_{m-1}-x_{m-2},\ x_1=1,\ x_2=3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, perfect-powers

I friend told me that apart from trivial ones, the elements in this sequence never equal powers of 3:
$$x_m=4x_{m-1}-x_{m-2},\ x_1=1,\ x_2=3.$$

Could you please help me to prove this?

Comment: let $x_m=3^m$ and see whether this could be a solution to your difference equation.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A001835

Comment: I can express it explicit, but that doesn't seem to help

Comment: Math-Fun, that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have:
$$ x_m = \frac{1}{6}\left[(3-\sqrt{3})(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(3+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3})^n\right]$$
and we may notice that $3x_m^2-2$ is always a square, so it is enough to prove that
$$ 3^{2k+1}-2 = a^2 \tag{1}$$
has the only solutions $(k,a)\in\{(0,1),(1,5)\}$. $(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$ 3 (3^k-1)(3^k+1) = (a-1)(a+1) \tag{2} $$
that is not difficult to study.

Comment: Is $(0,1)=(k,a)$ not included?

Comment: @MXYMXY: right, fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. (2) is actually where I started, and then I got to the expression I asked about. I'm not sure how I am supposed to conclude the that the 2 solutions are the only ones.